# What is the connection between figs and pride in the word Caprificus?

Tags: etymology, meaning, definitions

I have seen the definitions of caprificus (caper + ficus = goat + fig) include both pride and fig trees /goat-figs. Are goats considered particularly prideful? I would think they would be more associated with gluttony than any of the other sins.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Where have you seen such definitions? That might help giving a good answer.

Comment: At first I thought your question was a joke. *Caprificus,* a goat fig; *magnificus,* large fig; *beatificus,* a perfect fig.

Answer (score 2):

In its original sense, *capri-fīcus* just means "wild fig-tree". Its fruits are harder to eat and less pleasant than the domesticated fig-tree (*fīcus*), but goats can eat them just fine, so the Romans named it the "goat-fig".

However, one thing the *caprifīcus* was known for was its tenacity: it had a reputation for pushing its roots up underneath the pavement and ruining it. See Persius's *Satires* 1.25-6:

> quo didicisse, nisi hoc fermentum et quae semel intus innata est rupto iecore exierit **caprificus**?
>
> *What's the point of having learned, if not to let this roiling passion, this **caprifīcus** inside me, tear its way out of my liver all at once?*

I've never seen *caprifīcus* defined as "pride", but I'd guess it comes from this metaphorical usage: it's a tree that doesn't know its place, that strikes back against man-made walls and structures confining it and will happily tear down a house in order to keep growing where it likes.